# How do I include a Jquery UI slider in my view?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rubygems, slider

I'm trying to incorporate a slider (http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#installation) into my view, which is supposedly part of jquery-ui.  I have these in my Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

And when i open Gemfile.lock I see

```
jquery-rails (4.3.1)
  rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
  railties (>= 4.2.0)
  thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
  railties (>= 3.2.16)
```

But although I have this HTML on my page

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

and I include this Javascript

```
$('.slider').slider().slider('pips');
```

I get the JS console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

when my page loads.  The documentation says I have to include jQuery 2.1.1 and Jquery UI 2.1.1.  I can't tell if I'm doing that properly or not.

**Edit:** Including content of app/assets/application.js in response to answer given ...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using? Also, the problem is in development or production or both?

Comment: how about use the `javascript_include_tag' ? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag

Comment: @AniketShivam, I'm using Rails 5.0.1 on my development machine.

Comment: @Natalia - Just remove the //= require_tree and then check whether it is working or not

Answer (score 4):

Seems everything is ok, you need some customization like on the `assets/application.js` top of the file add sorting like

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Make sure `jquery` not rendering twice and your `slider` library include properly then edit your slider `JS` like below

```
(function($){
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('.slider').slider().slider('pips');
    });
});
```

Or like below

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $('.slider').slider().slider('pips');
});
```

For refactoring you can use this `js` on the same page underneath where your slider using `<script type="text/javascript"> .... </script>` tag

Restart the server for better response after implementing this

**Update On Answer Comment**

> The issue is you're probably calling the js function before it's (JS
>   Library) loaded. Also, check this

Hope it helps

Comment: the issue is you're probably calling the js function before it's loaded as @fool-dev is stating you need to invoke it after the page is ready. You can test if this is the case by opening the Developer Tools in your browser and pasting the jQuery function $('.slider').slider().slider('pips'); in the Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
Include the js from within the html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

See if it works after that.